# Why is the Measurement Result Always 1? (expected to find uniformly random measurement)

Tags: programming, quantum-state, measurement, cirq, random-quantum-circuit

I created a $|0\rangle$ state then applied $H$ gate to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$ and then I meausred my state. But I always found 1.
I expected to find 0 and 1 uniformly random like the case of beam splitter.

Here is my code:

```
qubit = cirq.NamedQubit("myqubit")
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubit))
for i in range(10):
    result2 = cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit')
    print(result2)
print(circuit)
# run simulation
result = cirq.Simulator().simulate(circuit)
print("result:")
print(result)
print(result2)
```

How can I find uniformly random result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not measuring your qubit. Look at what your `print(circuit)` is returning

```
myqubit: ───H───
```

You need to add the measurement gate to the circuit like so:

```
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubit), cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit'))
```

Printing this circuit returns `myqubit: ───H───M───`

In your case, with the loop; you can append the gates:

```
for i in range(10):
    circuit.append(cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit'))
```

Printing this one returns `myqubit: ───H───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───`

Both programs will get you the expected uniform random measurements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but when I try your method, result2 is coming as None. How can I save the result2 correctly? I tried this code scripts: `saver = []
# creates an equal superposition of |0> and |1> when simulated
qubit = cirq.NamedQubit("myqubit")
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubit), cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit'))
for i in range(10):
    result2= circuit.append(cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit'))
    saver=np.append(saver,result2) `

Comment: And the result is not uniform...

Comment: `circuit.append` doesn't return anything, that's why it returns None. When you call `circuit.append` it adds that gate to the `cirq.Circuit` object. What do you mean the result is not uniform? When we run the circuit 1000 times we get half and half.

`qubit = cirq.NamedQubit("myqubit") circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubit),cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit') ) result = cirq.Simulator().run(circuit, repetitions=1000).histogram(key='myqubit') print(result)`

Returns a uniform distribution

`Counter({1: 509, 0: 491})`

Comment: Thanks, now I was writing to you. I did it. When I run the code, I found 400  and 600 so it seems to me not uniform. the last question is that, how can I save the just output in a list, I al trying to save but I al saving all information and I can not use  `[ ]` for taking first element

Comment: Uniform does not mean 50/50 exactly. Think about flipping a coin. When you flip a coin a thousand times, you will not get a perfect balance between Head and Tails. The result is still uniform. This program is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

@Victory Omole already answered the question.

But here is the fixed code if you are interested.

```
qubit = cirq.NamedQubit("myqubit")
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubit))
circuit.append(cirq.measure(qubit, key='result'))
print(circuit)
s=cirq.Simulator()
samples=s.run(circuit, repetitions=1000)
print('Single measurement result:' ,samples.histogram(key='result'))

print('****************************************')
circuit2 = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H(qubit))
for i in range(10):
    circuit2.append(cirq.measure(qubit, key='myqubit'))
print(circuit2)
samples2 = s.run(circuit, repetitions=1000)
print('Hadamard follows by 10 measurements result:' ,samples2.histogram(key='result'))
```

The output would be something like:

```
myqubit: ───H───M('result')───
Single measurement result: Counter({0: 501, 1: 499})
****************************************
myqubit: ───H───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───M───
Hadamard follows by 10 measurements result: Counter({1: 502, 0: 498})
```

**Update:** If you want to print out the counter, that is, accessing the result at each shot/experiment then you can do the following: (There is a better to do this probabbly but I don't really use `cirq`...)

```
samples2 = [s.run(circuit, repetitions=1) for i in range(10) ]
samples2
```

The output would be something like:

```
[result=1,
 result=0,
 result=1,
 result=1,
 result=1,
 result=0,
 result=1,
 result=0,
 result=0,
 result=0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I save the ourput in a list? I want to save just output like 01010101010 in a list however I could not access the just output part

Comment: To save it to a list, append the result to a list `list = [] result = cirq.Simulator().run(circuit, repetitions=1000) list.append(result)`

Comment: thanks ! I tried numpy array and it saved all information inside list but with python list, it worked Thanks :)